# Show/Hide thumbnail sidebar by default in PDF

Tags: xetex, navigation, sidebar

Whenever I generate a PDF with XeLaTeX, it seems to contain some property or metadata that indicates to PDF viewers that the thumbnail drawer/sidebar should be opened by default. When opening my one-page pdf, both in Firefox's pdf viewer and in MacOS's Preview app, the sidebar automatically opens to display a single thumbnail:

Firefox: [image: Firefox pdf viewer]

MacOS Preview:[image: MacOS Preview]

I know that its something specific to the PDF file, because opening other PDFs does not open the sidebar in the same way.

I'm using Byungjin Park's Awesome-CV template here: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV

Is there some kind of setting in XeLaTeX, or in the LaTeX template itself, where this behavior can be set? According to [this answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1178573) in Mozilla's support forums, their viewer opens the sidebar "when specified by the PDF itself" but I cannot locate how to set this preference.

Comment: Use `\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseThumbs}`   (assuming that your template loads hyperref).

Comment: Thank you! hyperref was the dependency causing it, and `pdfpagemode=UseNone` hid the sidebar in Firefox. Preview still shows it but web browsers were my main concern.